# Given the two functions $f(x)=x^2+3x+5$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{2-|x-4|}$ work out $g^{-1}$ (Sweden 1961)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse-function

Given the two functions $f(x)=x^2+3x+5$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{2-|x-4|}$ work out $g^{-1}$ for some subdomain.

I have managed to prove that $g^{-1}$ exists in the following way:

$g(x)=\sqrt{6-x}$ with $x\in[4,6]$ we have that g is 1-1 in $[4,6]$ and hence $g^{-1}$ exists.

This is where I got stuck and couldn't continue. Could you please explain how to work out $g^{-1}$ and explain every step of your thought process as well as intuitively, how you though of each step?

Comment: the function $f(x)$ given as a lark?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean @phdmba7of12

Comment: *I don't understand what you mean* --- Is the function $f(x)$ intended to mislead solvers? We don't have to know what $f(x)$ is to find $g^{-1}.$ Indeed, to find $g^{-1},$ we don't have to know what $h(x)$ is, or what a Riemann manifold is, or what the $5338$th decimal of $\pi$ is.

Comment: Also, what about x between $2$ and $4$?

Comment: $g(x)$ is a many-one function and is not invertible in its domain. Do we have to find it's inverse for a specific subset of the domain?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro If that's what lark means then yes it is a lark

Comment: @phdmba7of12 yes it is a lark

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb yes you are supposed to find it for a subdomain

Comment: Personally, I'd use the phrase [red herring](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/WhatIs/WhatIsRedHerring.shtml). I once used this phrase on a 1976 homework assignment (some upper level math class, forgot which), saying that we didn't need one of the assumptions for a result I was proving (and thinking that I was clever in noticing this), and naturally when I got the assignment back, the professor had indicated on it an incorrect step in my proof.

Comment: $g(x) \ne \sqrt {6-x}$ if $x  < 4$.  Consider $x =3$.  Then $g(3) = \sqrt {2-|x-4|}=\sqrt{2-(-1)} = \sqrt {2-1} =\sqrt 1 = 1$.

Comment: "yes, you are supposed to find it for a subdomain "  Which one?  Why did you pick $[4,6]$.  Why didn't you pick $[2,4]$? or why didn't you pick "The irrationals between $2$ and $4$ and the rationals between $4$ and $6$"? Or if you want to make this easy why didn't you pick subdomain $\{5\}$ that be easy.  If we restrict the domain to $x\in \{5\}$ then $g:\{5\}\to \{1\}$ via $g(x)=5$ and the inverse is $g^{-1}(y) = 5$.

Comment: FWIW.  "Doing something for a lark" means doing something for no purpose except it's fun.  A "red herring" means something put in deliberately to mislead you.  In this case pointing out $f(x)=x^2+3x+5$ is about as relevant and as important as saying that Chilly Willy was created by the Walter Lanz Studios in 1953.

Comment: "I have managed to prove that g−1

exists in the following way:

g(x)=6−x−−−−−√
with x∈[4,6] we have that g is 1-1 in [4,6] and hence g−1 exists."  But $g(x)=\sqrt{x-2}$ on $[2,4]$ and on the domain $[2,6]$ we have $g$ is *NOT* one to one so $g^{-1}$ does *NOT* exist.    There are subdomains where $g$ is one to one but that is true of *ALL* functions-- all functions-- have a subdomain upon which they are one to one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have highlighted, an inverse exists, and I shall find it for the subdomain $[4,6]$.

In this subdomain, $|x-4| = x-4$, since $x > 4$. The equation then becomes
$$y = \sqrt{2-x+4} = \sqrt{6-x}$$
square both sides to obtain
$$y^2 = 6-x \implies x = 6-y^2$$
Therefore, the inverse function for the subdomain $[4,6]$ is $f^{-1}: [0,\sqrt{2}] \rightarrow [4,6], f^{-1}(x) = 6-x^2$. Here's a graph showing the given function and it's inverse (both of them are mirror images of each other about $y=x$.

[image: graph]

Answer (score 0):

Why did you restrict to the domain $[4,6]$?  It is not the complete domain of $g$.

the domain is all $x$ where $|x-4| \le 2$ so $0\le x-4 \le 2$ or $-2 \le x-4 \le 0$ so $4\le x \le 6$ or $2\le x \le 4$. So the domain is $[2,6]$

And we can easily see that $g$ is not one to one because for any $x \in (4,6]$ where $g(x) = \sqrt {2-|x-4|} =K$ we can have an $x' = 8-x\in [2,4)$ where $g(x') = \sqrt{2 -|(8-x)-4|}=\sqrt{2-|4-x|}=\sqrt{2-|x-4|}=K$.  For example $g(5) =\sqrt{2-|5-4|} = \sqrt{2-|3-4|} = g(3)$ and $g(4.1)=\sqrt{2-|4.1-4|} = \sqrt{2-|4-3.9|}=g(3.9)$ etc.

So no inverse will exist.

To find the inverse (if it exists)

Let $y=g^{-1}(x)$ so $x = g(g^{-1}(x)) = g(y) = \sqrt{2-|y-4|}$ so we solve for $y$.

$x = \sqrt{2-|y-4|}$ so

$x^2 = 2-|y-4|$

If $y \ge 4$ then $x^2 = 2-(y-4)=6-y$ and $y= 6-x^2$.

If $y < 4$ then $x^2 = 2-(4-y)=y-2$ and $y=x^2+2$

But that is not a well defined function.  If $6-x^2 > 4 > x^2 + 2$, that is to say if $x^2 < 2$ then we have no we to pick which value $y=g^{-1}(x)$ should be.

so the inverse does not exist and the function is not one to one.